# why ie8 CORS / XDomainRequest doesn't send cookie?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, xdomainrequest

I've managed to make a CORS request on IE8 using XDomainRequest. However it seems the cookies are not sent on IE8. Is there any hack for that ? The request is made from buy.example.com to buy.api.example.com

Comment: You have set a domain for the cookie?

Comment: IE's XDomainRequest implementation of CORS doesn't allow cookies to be passed at all, for security reasons says Microsoft..

Comment: @Mihai Check out point 5 -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: @SeanCocteau thanks for the reference Sean. Seems that microsoft did it again . Just another crap that we have to deal with.

Comment: @Neo the only way is to include the cookie values/auth token in the query string ... basically I modified our authentication filter to check for auth cookie value in the query string if cookies are not sent /detected ( we some something like example.com/API?sessionId=$cookie_session_id&other parameters )

Comment: @mihai thats exactly what I ended up doing, I'm using jquery with the cookie plugin so I send the cookies as get params in ajax requests! :)

Comment: @Neo if you still do that make sure you are using SSL otherwise the clients are sitting ducks !

Comment: @mihai yeah I know. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way except to include the authentication cookie value / token in the query string e.g. :

```
 buy.api.example.com/?sessionId=$sessionId&otherparameters=test
```

and set your webservice to check the query string if cookies are not present.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. If you use SSL on the non-default https port, it will keep sending the cookies.
For example, if your URL is something like this https://example.com:8443/xxxx, then it will send the cookies.

I experience the same issue you have. My web app (internal web app) was working with https but in a non standard port and it just works fine. When I configure to use 443, it stops working because the cookies are not sent by XDomainRequest object.

I hope this will help